# How can change the content for social media site sharing in nopCommerce

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, social-networking, nopcommerce

How can I change the content,url,and title for sharing the Product registration page in social Media like facebook.linkedIn in nopCommerce.?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This data is parsed by social plug-ins from title and meta tags on product page. 
So you can:

1. Change product data in administration panel (title, description)
2. Add special fields to product (but database change is required) and add Open graph meta tags with this data
3. Change share buttons code in administration panel, catalog settings, 'Share button code' property.